# Listview looked like a ListBox in the attached picture in the Universal App

Tags: windows, xaml, listview, win-universal-app

What do I need to do to Listview looked like a ListBox in the attached picture in the Universal App or whether there is an easier way to get a similar-looking list?

https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC505349.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to ask, but I'll give it a shot.

You can use a ListView and then set its DataTemplate to effectively make it look exactly as u want.
For example:

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition />
               <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property2}" />
        </Grid>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

Where Property1 and Property2 are bindable properties of an item in your ItemsSource.